# How do I write a unit test for a void method and create a mock dataset and a datarow(Both dataset and datarow are strongly typed)?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method whose return type is void. This method has two parameters, a strongly typed datarow and dataset.

```
private void Check(Dataset testDB, DataRow testRow)
{

 if(testRow.Amount>10)
 {
    decimal rate = testRow.Rate;

    if(rate >= 100)
    {
      AddData(testDB,testRow,"some text");
    }

 }

}

private void AddData(Dataset testDB, DataRow testRow, string notes)
{
  Dataset.StudentRow newRow=testDB.Students.NewStudentRow();
  .
  .
  .
  testDB.Students.AddStudentRow(newRow);
}
```

Comment: WHat language are we in here?

Answer (score 1):

You will not do any mocking. You will use real DataSet and DataRow and assert that data are correctly defined in data set after calling the method. You generally need several unit tests to cover the method:

- Unit test with row having Amount 10
- Unit test with row having Amount 11 but rate 99
- Unit test with row having Amount 11 and rate 100